# LDAP with .NET Core 3.1 as docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, ldap

I am developing an application based on .NET Core (3.1) which must connect to a LDAP server. My development machine running Windows, but the application will have to run as docker container.

- I used the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace but I got an error

  > Unable to load shared library 'Kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies
- So I added a `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5` but I got

  > System.DirectoryServices is not supported on this platform
- finally I added `Novell.Directory.Ldap` Version="3.6.0".

Unfortunately, I got

> Unable to connect to server (91) System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known"

although that the connection success when I use `System.DirectoryServices` with the same domain name.

```
 public bool ValidateUser(string domainName, string username, string password)
        {
            string userDn = $"{username}@{domainName}";
            try
            {
                var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection {SecureSocketLayer = true };
                ldapConnection.Connect(domainName, 389);
                ldapConnection.Bind(userDn, password);
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
```

what can I do to solve this error, or is there a new solution.

Comment: Based on these errors, it looks like you're trying to run this in a Linux container. What does your Dockerfile look like? How are you building it? And from what environment?

Comment: BTW, .NET Core 3.1 has been EOL since Dec. 2022. Might be time to upgrade to a supported version as well.

Comment: The problem has been solved when I change LDAP DNS to IP.